# how to handle error while extracing the zip file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, fs

i am trying to upload zip file and then i have to extract it in server side and also i have to handle error while extracting that zip file.to extract i am trying like this

```
var zip = new AdmZip(x);

zip.extractAllTo('target path');
```

the extractAllTo not contain call back function ,if it is contain that i can handle err easily so let me know how to handle err while extracting zip file.

i am creating one tmp folder and after upload file and then i keep that uploaded file into tmp folder and then i am storing that uploaded file into original folder and i will take that path to store db(mongodb).After stored data i got stored result in callback function within that callback function i have tried to remove that tmp folder but i could not remove it.i have tired to remove without that data stored callback function it is working . what mistake i did.how to resolve it.i have tried like this

```
db.save({'filepath':'xxxxx'},function(err,data)
{

     if(data)
     {
        fs.rmdir('xxxx/xxxxx',function(err)
       {
             if(err)
             {
                console.log('err')

             }else 
            {
               console.log('removed');

            } 

       });
     }
});
```

i am always received in console that err.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking in the code from adm-zip, the only way is to embed extraction in a try {} catch statement:

```
var zip = new AdmZip(x);

try { 
    zip.extractAllTo('target path');
} catch ( e ) { 
    console.log( 'Caught exception: ', e );
}
```

Comment: if error is not exist ,from where i should start next function . can i start with in try black like this try { zip.extractAllTo('target path'); db.find({'username':xxxx},function(err,result){console.log(result) });) }

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your library is synchronous, which is why it doesn't use callbacks. If you are uploading a zip file to a server, synchronous calls will halt your entire server for all clients and thus you should switch to an asynchronous library to do this work. FYI for the synchronous version, to handle errors, you would use a `try/catch` structure as the exceptions thrown are in a single execution stack.